# Header banner to start CSS after another div

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

My code with css is defined in my JSP and css as follows:

basic.css

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: #eeeeec url(../images/image1.gif) repeat-x;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
```

layout.css

```
#Outage{
        width: 984px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #bgd{
        background-image: url(../images/image2.gif);
        background-position: top right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #Wrapper{
        width: 984px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /*-----------BANNER-----------*/
    #banner{
        padding-right: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

header.jsp

```
<div id="bgd">
    <div id="Wrapper">    
    <div><img src="<%=contextPath%>/images/logo.gif" alt="test and 123" width="255" height="34" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
    <div id="procNae"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
<div>
```

Now I want to add outage at the top of all this as follows:

```
<div id="Outage">      
    <div id="notificationDiv" style="display:none; width: 255px; height: 34px;">Test</div>
</div>
<div id="bgd">...////...</div>
```

But this is acting as a layover on "bgd", so the img gets cuts off. I would want actually "Outage" to have a plain background and "bgd" and its css to start only after "Outage". Any help highly appreciated.

```css
basic.css * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #eeeeec url(../images/image1.gif) repeat-x;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

layout.css #bgd {
  background-image: url(../images/image2.gif);
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 984px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*-----------BANNER-----------*/

#banner {
  padding-right: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgd">
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <div><img src="https://data.photofunky.net/output/image/4/1/7/1/4171e9/photofunky.gif" alt="test and 123" width="255" height="34" />
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
      <div id="procNae"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see that the div outage gets the same body as the dbg. Is there a way to apply body to my 1st div and bgd has its own div?

Comment: Include css for `Outage` element

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to fix your end divs

Comment: @ mplungjan thank you

Comment: @Mr T added css for Outage

Comment: Looks fine to me, might be something else.

Comment: @Mr T - 
I see that the div outage gets the same body as the dbg. Is there a way to apply body to my 1st div and bgd has its own body?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `body`? Is it the background image which is set on `body` tag visible on `bgd` element? If so, set a `background-color` to your `bgd` element